# python itertool combination list is not complete

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have a list with 11 elements and i need all possible tuples with a length of 4 out of it. So I found the function `combinations` in Itertools.

However, it delivers only 210 tuples instead of 11^4 = 14641. I checked with the `print` function and many of them are missing.

What can I do, or what is the problem?

```
atom = [0, 5, 6, 12, 10, 13, 11, 9, 1, 2]
atoms = list(itertools.combinations(atom,4))
```

Answer (score 5):

`combinations` gives you tuples in sorted order, no repeats.  It sounds like you instead want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
atom = range(11)

print(len(list(product(atom, repeat=4))))
# 14641
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands If you use a list that actually has 11 elements, you'll get 14641

Comment: my mistake +1 (might be worth pointing out that their `atom` is length 10)

Answer (score 1):

Sure - you get all the combinations of your list (which contains 10 elements).
`combinations` returns all distinct unordered numbers in your list combined as 4 elements.

The number of possible combinations is 10 over 4 - this is (10*9*8*7 / 4*3*2*1) - which is exactly 210.

See also [Combinations Calculator](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php)

`permuations` is maybe what you want - it returns all ordered combinations - e.g. it would yield [0 5 6 12], [5 0 6 12] whereas `combinations` would only yield [0 5 6 12] in that case.

But `permutations` is also not 11^4, but 10*9*8*7 elements. Correct would be 10^4 in your case maybe - and you have to use `product` if you *really* want something like [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,5], etc.

Comment: thank you. I was looking for permutations. Yeah it is only 10 element I misscounted

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [permutation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) not [combination](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). Combinations not returning

> [1, 2, 3, 4] and [1, 3, 2, 4]

They only return different value sets. You can use permutation as follow

```
list(itertools.permutations(atoms, 4))
```

if you want to get values like follow

> [1, 1, 1, 2] and [1, 1, 2, 1]

You need to write `product` as @Patrick Haugh mentioned